# DZ.player.prev() failing silently

Tags: deezer

Sometimes when I use DZ.player.prev() the command fails silently. It is not a problem with my code, since I tested using the commands on the console.

I try to use DZ.player.prev(), and the player does not return to previous song. The player is not on repeat or shuffle mode. I also check to see if is there a previous song on the player with DZ.player.getTrackList() and DZ.player.getCurrentIndex().

Comment: Could you give us some scenarios to replicate the issue you encountered please? Thank you!

Comment: When I use DZ.player.playTracks to load the entire playlist to the player, the DZ.player.prev works just fine. But when I load tracks one by one with DZ.player.addToQueue, the command (DZ.player.prev) behaves like described above.